# Angular material 2 not rendering styles for components

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use the latest version of angular material in my project and was following the instructions from the official website.
Apparently materialmodule is not part of this anymore and including it in my project was initially giving me compiler errors.
I have individually imported the required modules but the style doen't get rendered on screen.
What am I missing?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule,MatSidenavModule,MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,MatCheckboxModule,MatSelectModule, MatListModule,MatButtonToggleModule,MatTableModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(MockData),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
```

Resource.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-container class="ui-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="ui-sidenav">
  Jolly good
    </md-sidenav>

      <div class="sidenav-content">
        <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
          Open Selection Menu
        </button>
      </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Current output

Comment: May you forgot to add a theme. @See: Step4 https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: you need to include theme

Comment: I did actually! Forgot to mention it here.
style.css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Comment: For me it worked only I added `"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` to the styles section in `.angular-cli.json` itself. I am not sure if your _relative URL_ is properly resolved, actually...

Comment: Convert from `md` to `mat`.